# Prove $Ra/Rab$ $\cong_R$ $R/Rb$ , with $R$ a domain and $a,b$ not zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I posted a question yesterday on how to prove the following :" $Ra/Rab$ $\cong_R$ $R/Rb$ " and the answer I got said the homomorphism $\phi :$$R$ $\rightarrow$ $Ra/Rab$ : $x$ $\mapsto$ $ax + Rab$ would be the solution, as by the isomorphism theorem the Kernel of this map is $Rb$ and thus the isomorphism in the title holds.

Now I have been thinking about the question and I am still stuck. If the mapping is a homomorphism and we take an element $x'$ of $Rb$, $\phi(x')$ would be $ax'= ax''b$, but if $Rb$ is the kernel of $\phi$, $ax''b$ has to be divisible by $ab$ and since we don't know if $R$ is commutative we can't say for a fact that $ab$ $|$ $ax''b$ or any element of $Rb$ ?

[Here is the link to the original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3650668/let-r-be-a-domain-and-a-b-in-r-prove-r-rb-cong-r-ra-rab)

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for the edit

Comment: I've no counterexample off the top of my head, but are you sure this holds if $R$ is not commutative? By the way, “domain” usually implies commutative.

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much for the answer, the way a domain is defined in the course notes does not imply commutativity, It's simply $ab$ is never $0$ if neither $a$ or $b$ is $0$. Are you saying that the statement in the title would not per se be true if R is not commutative ?

Comment: Suppose $f\colon R/Rb\to Ra/Rab$ is a homomorphism. Then $f(1+Rb)=xa+Rab$, for some $x$; since $b\in Rb$, we have $f(0+Rb)=f(b+Rb)=bf(1+Rb)=bxa+Rab$. Hence we need $bxa\in Rab$. Do you see where the problem is? There might be *no* element $x$ such that $bxa\in Rab$.

Comment: @egreg Isee, so the above statement could hold if R is a field ?

Comment: If $R$ is a (skew) field, the the isomorphism is trivial: both are the zero module.